# Core Data: Sort by Relationship's Attribute

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I'm building an [open-source clone of iPhone's native Messages app called AcaniChat on GitHub](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat).

I have a `Conversation` entity and a `Message` entity with a `sentDate` attribute. Each `Conversation` can have many `Message`s. How do I fetch `Conversation`s sorted by the `sentDate` of it's oldest `Message`?

Comment: I've posted a similar solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11550855/306764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of doing this is by adding an attribute to the `Conversation` entity called `lastMessageSentDate` and, every time a `Message` comes in and gets added to a `Conversation`, setting that conversation's `lastMessageSentDate` to that message's `sentDate`. I'll also probably want to add an attribute called `lastMessageText` to the `Conversation` entity as well because I want to show the text of the last message for a conversation on the `ConversationsViewController` (just like the native iPhone Messages app does), and doing so will save me from having to do another Core Data fetch for the `Message`.

Actually, I just had an idea! Maybe I can sort `Conversation`s by `messages.@max.sortedDate`, according to [Xcode Documentation: Key-Value Coding Programming Guide: Collection Operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).

Comment: Your first idea might be more efficient since it eliminates the need to compute the maximum date for each Conversation.messages collection every time you fetch Conversations!

Comment: or just have a `lastMessage` in a `Conversation` instead of `lastMessageSentDate` and `lastMessageText` :)

Comment: @MattDiPasquale I tried your idea. It didn’t work. See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748852/how-to-sort-core-data-results-based-on-an-attribute-of-related-object-collection